# Android How to play and surf youtube videos on webview

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I am developing an application in Android, where I should be able to pass an youtube url in webview and play and surf through it. The progress so far is that I can see the initial screen but the play button is not playing the video.
 In the emulator its still playing the sound but in devices the sound is also not getting played,though I can surf through the youtube videos and perform all other functionality.i am posting the code below:

```
    public class YoutubePlayActivity extends Activity {
    String myUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvwnjWcG250&feature=related";
     wv1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    wv1.setWebViewClient(new myClient());
    wv1.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvwnjWcG250&feature=related");
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 

    wv1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    wv1.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    wv1.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

class myClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }

}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                            .invoke(wv1, (Object[]) null);

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {

    } catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {

    } catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {

    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {

    }
}
public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
            FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
            if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                frame.removeView(video);
                video.start();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}